# Load multiple node js servers on webstorm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, webstorm, nodemon

I have multiple servers aggregated under a main server. For instance:
`Pet.js` is the main server with link to ===>> `{Cat_Server.js , Dog_Server.js , Tiger_Server.js}`. How can i run all the servers at the same time in Webstorm? On the command line i could do:

```
forever start Cat_Server.js
forever start Dog_Server.js
```

Comment: `forever start Cat_Server.js &` if on a *nix platform?

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis yes, but is there anyway i could do it on webstorm?